# Require two words separated by space in input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field in which I would like to force the user to enter two words separated by a space. If only one word is entered, it must not let the user submit the form.

```
<input type="text" name="nom"placeholder="Prenom Nom" required>
```

Comment: You mean the entered value should contain exactly two space-separated words?

Comment: this is exactly what i mean

Comment: Validating names is a fool's errand. Consider the actor Dick van Dyke, the Nobel prize-winning physicists Klaus von Klitzing and Gerard 't Hooft... And then there are plenty of people who, genuinely, have a single name.

Comment: Or consider the noted SO contributor T. J. Crowder.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a pattern

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Prenom Nom" required="required" pattern="^\S+\s\S+$" name="nom">
```

that matches any character group (but not space), a space, and any character group (but not space)

Comment: Good Answer. But, `pattern` attribute is not supported on safari browser

Comment: @Sachin - noone uses Safari anyway, and it doesn't support any kind of HTML5 validation, not even `required`

Comment: agree that safari users are less. But, most users on ios are safari users :)

Comment: So find a plugin that adds the polyfill for html5 validation, there are tons out there.

Comment: @adeneo: *"noone uses Safari anyway"* Um...the *vast* majority of iPad/iPod/iPhone users use Safari, it's [34% of the global mobile browser market](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qpcustomd=1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I know, it was meant as a joke, sort of, but Safari still doesn't support HTML5 validation, and the OP is already using that with `require`, so assuming `pattern` is okay as well, wouldn't be a stretch. Your french is better than mine btw, did even catch the *"nom"* (name) until you commented on it, and validating names, requiring exactly two names, would be a bad idea anyway.